# Line of best fit for a log graph in python 3.3

Tags: python, numpy, graph, line, gradient

I'm doing a piece of work that is basically a random walk but with a probability of the person getting arrested after each step, n. I start with K people and then I have a graph which plots log(k) vs. n where k is the number of people that have survived n steps.

```
plt.plot(n,numpy.log(k)
```

I need to find the gradient of this graph but also want to do a line of best fit, any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a, b = np.polyfit(n, np.log(k), 1)
```

[will return the coefficients](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) of the best-fit line, `logk = a n + b`.

Comment: Thank you I have just tried this, do I need to print a and b? I didn't print them before and no figures of a and b appeared, when I tried to print them it just said nan?!